# Oracle PL SQL - Sort column value beginning with '_" then followed by alphabets

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL, I want to sort the below data with values beginning with `"_"` followed by `alphabet` (without using COLLATE)

```
    AE
    BASMI1_02
    CBPBC_01
    _TYPERR
    AE1_01
    AE1_03
    AEPS
    AEYN
    ASAS1TABLE
    ASAS1_01
    CBPBC_01B
    CM
```

as

```
_TYPERR
AE
AE1_01
AE1_03
AEPS
AEYN
ASAS1_01
ASAS1TABLE
BASMI1_02
CBPBC_01
CBPBC_01B
CM
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select *
from table
order by case 
        when col like '\_%' escape '\'
            then 0
        else 1
        end,
    col;
```

It defines a custom sort order using case Statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want the underscore values to be sorted as well then do a union separating the two, simply put:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col LIKE '\_%'
ORDER BY col

UNION

SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col NOT LIKE '\_%' 
ORDER BY col;
```